# How do I access a record from another procedure?

Tags: java, record

So I am having an issue where I would like to create a record in one procedure, then alter the attributes of that record using other procedures and functions.

```
  import java.util.Scanner; // Imports scanner utility
  import java.util.Random;
  import java.lang.Math;

  class alienPet
  {
      public void main (String[] param)
      {
          // We want to call all of the functions
          // and procedures to make an interactive
          // alien program for the user.

          welcomeMessage();
          alienCreation();

          System.exit(0);

      } // END main

        /* ***************************************
        *   Define a method to obtain the users input
        * and start the correct method.
        */

        public static String userInput (String message)
        {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          String inp;
          print(message);
          inp = scan.nextLine();
              return inp;
        } // END userInput

        /* ***************************************
      * Define a method to print messages.
      */

      public static void print (String message)
      {
          System.out.println(message);
          return;
      } // END print

      /* ***************************************
      * Define a method to 
      */

      public static void welcomeMessage ()
      {
        print("Thank you for playing the pet alien game");
        print("In this game, you will have to look after your own alien.");
        print("There is multiple aspects to looking after your alien, such as:");
        print("Hunger, Behaviour and Thirst."); 
        print("");
        print("When prompted, you can use the following commands:");
        print("feed -> Replenishes alien to max hunger level");
        print("drink -> Replenished thirst level to max");
        print("");
          return;
      } // END 


      /* ***************************************
      * Define a method to 
      */

      public void alienCreation ()
      {
        Alien ufo = new Alien();
        ufo.name = userInput("What would you like to name your new alien?");
        ufo.hungerRate = ranNum(1, 6);
        print("On a scale of 1-6, your alien, " + ufo.name + ", has a hunger rate of " + ufo.hungerRate);
        alienBehaviour(ufo.hungerRate);
          return;
      } // END alienCreation

      public void alienBehaviour (int hunger) {
          if (hunger <= 2){
              print(ufo.name + " is very hungry, and is dangerously angry!!");
              String action = userInput("You should feed it as soon as possible. (by typing 'feed')");
              if (action.equals("feed")){
                  feedAlien();
              }else if (action.equals("drink")) {
                  alienDrink();
              }else{
                  print("That is a dangerous decision.");
              }
          }else if (hunger <= 4) {
            print(ufo.name + " is mildly hungry, but is in a calm state.");
              String action = userInput("Would you like to take any actions?");
              if (action.equals("feed")){
                  feedAlien();
              }else if (action.equals("drink")) {
                  alienDrink();
              }else{
                  print("Okay.");
              }
          }else if (hunger <= 6) {
            print(ufo.name + " is not hungry and is in a happy state.");
              String action = userInput("Would you like to take any actions?");
              if (action.equals("feed")){
                  feedAlien();
              }else if (action.equals("drink")) {
                  alienDrink();
              }else{
                  print("Okay.");
              }
          }
      }

      public void feedAlien() {
          ufo.hungerRate = 6;
          print(ufo.name + "'s hunger level replenished to max level 6.");
          print(ufo.name + " is now at a happy level.");
      }

      public void alienDrink() {
        ufo.thirst = 6;
        print(ufo.name + "'s thirst level replenished to max level 6.");
    }

      public static int ranNum(int min, int max){ // A function that generates a random integer wihin a given range.
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.ints(min,(max+1)).findFirst().getAsInt();
    } // END ranNum

  } // END class alienPet

  class Alien {
      String name;
      int age = 0;
      int hungerRate;
      int thirst = 6;
  }
```

Obviously, some of the annotations are incomplete as of this time, but the issue I am having is in the alienBehaviour(), feedAlien() and alienDrink() procedures, I cannot seem to access the record created in the alienCreation() procedure.
The errors are all the same and is as follows:

```
alienPet.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
              print(ufo.name + " is very hungry, and is dangerously angry!!");
                    ^
  symbol:   variable ufo
  location: class alienPet
```

Now I am new to java, so I'm not sure whether I have to make the record global or something, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared inside of  a method are called `local` variables and are likely disposed of when the method finishes executing.

Variables declared outside any function are called `instance` variables and they can be accessed (used) on any function in the program.

You are looking  for an instance `Alien` `ufo` variable.

```
class alienPet{ // It is recommended you use the java naming convention.
    Alien myAlien = new Alien();
    // alienPet a = new alienPet();
    // a.myAlien; // you could potentially do this to get an alien from an alienPet class
    void someVoid(){
        Alien otherAlien;
    }
    void errorVoid(){
        otherAlien.toString(); 
// causes an error, the otherAlien variable is never visible to errorVoid as it is a local variable
        myAlien.toString(); // OK
    }
}
```

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 1):

You're having problems with the scope of your variable. Variables are only valid within the curly braces which they were declared in.

**WRONG**

```
public void alienCreation ()
{
    Alien ufo = new Alien();
    ufo.name = userInput("What would you like to name your new alien?");
    ufo.hungerRate = ranNum(1, 6);
    print("On a scale of 1-6, your alien, " + ufo.name + ", has a hunger rate of " + ufo.hungerRate);
    alienBehaviour(ufo.hungerRate);
    return;
} // END alienCreation and of the scope of your variable ufo
```

**RIGHT**

```
class alienPet
{
    Alien ufo;
    [...]
    public void alienCreation ()
    {
        ufo = new Alien();
        ufo.name = userInput("What would you like to name your new alien?");
        ufo.hungerRate = ranNum(1, 6);
        print("On a scale of 1-6, your alien, " + ufo.name + ", has a hunger rate of " + ufo.hungerRate);
        alienBehaviour(ufo.hungerRate);
        return;
    } // END alienCreation and your variable ufo will be initialized afterwards
}
```

Comment: But you can access static variables from other classes outside of the curly braces.

Comment: They don't have to be `static`, just `public`. You won't be able to access a `private static` variable outside of the curly braces... But that's a completely different topic!

Comment: To access a non-static variable from another class, if I recall correctly, you have to have an object of that class. For example, in your "RIGHT" example, to get the Alien ufo, you would have to call something like `new alienPet().ufo`.

Comment: Oh my, yes. But this has nothing to do with scope. These are the basics of OOP. But Scope has nothing to do with OOP either. It also exists in non-OOP-languages... You might confuse a beginner much more than helping him...